# Send UDP Protocol in node.js without broadcasting

Tags: node.js

I am developing an application to communicate with the hardware device programmed in C via UDP communication in node.js

I want to send a message to specific hardware as the hardware is having its own ip address but when i try to send a message using **send()** method it broadcast my message to all other devices connected in my network.

I want to send message to specific device only. so i tried to set **setBroadcast(false)** but then to it broadcast my message to all devices connected in the network

```
Please find the below mentioned code :

var dgram = require('dgram');
const net = require("net")
const server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
      call to funcion1();
});
server.on('listening', () => {
     call to funcion2();
 });
server.on('error', (err) => {
     call to funcion3();
});

server.bind({
    address: serverConfig.host,
    port: serverConfig.port,
    exclusive: false
}, () => {

        //server.setBroadcast(false);
});
```